# Reading file into 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

So i'm trying to read from a text file by bytes, and then read char of it.
but i'm trying to insert it into a 2D array , which is ankoshh.

Any help is appreciated :)

```
public class SteamOutputToFile 
{


public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int row;
        int col;
        String [][] ankoshh = new String[row][col];
        try{
        InputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream("E:\\testing.txt");

    int data = inputstream.read();
    while(data != -1) {
      //do something with data...
      System.out.print((char)data);

      data = inputstream.read();
    }
    }
    catch (IOException ioexception){
        System.out.println("File input error occured!");
        ioexception.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i=0; i<ankoshh.length;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<ankoshh[i].length;j++)
        {
            ankoshh[row][col] = (char)data[i];
        }
```

Comment: Data is used as both array  and int in your code. Which is it? You can read files to byte arrays with InputStream.read. Are you aware that ankoshh is actually three dimensional in your example?

Comment: And you are also using `ankoshh` as if it were a `char[][]` but it is declared as `String[][]`.  Also, it seems totally unclear what you are trying to achieve.  A file has no natural representation as a 2D array.  Where should what data go?

Comment: @5gon12eder, he has preallocated array, so probably dimension sizes are known.

Comment: Data i'm using it as an array, and could please explain the InputStream.read part? 
sorry if my program has multiple errors, finishing a project with little time :)

Answer (score 0):

Apache common-io greatly help you to do that, it is not necessary to use FileInputStream.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class Test
{
   public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
   {
      File file = new File (args[0]);
      List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines (file);

      String[][]ankoshh = new String [lines.size ()][];

      int line_index=0;
      for (String line:lines)
      {
         String[] caracters = line.split("(?!^)");
         ankoshh[line_index++] = caracters;
      }
   }
}
```

If file are really big you can also use line iterator:

```
LineIterator it=FileUtils.lineIterator (file);
while (it.hasNext ())
...
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Fred

Comment: I'm using the File inputSteam because its the only thing i took and i'm trying to understand it, but i'll look into the method you just mentioned, Thanks!